# How can I read an image from Azure blob storage directly using Opencv without downloading it to a local file?

Tags: python-2.7, azure, azure-blob-storage, opencv3.0

I want to read an image from Azure blob storage by using opencv 3 in Python 2.7.
How to do this without downloading the blob to a local file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my experience, you can try to use `get_blob_to_bytes` method to download the blob as a byte array and covert it to a opencv image, as my sample code below.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

account_name = '<your-storage-account>'
account_key = '<your accout key>'
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)

container_name = 'mycontainer'
blob_name = 'test.jpg'
blob = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(container_name, blob_name)

import numpy as np
import cv2
# use numpy to construct an array from the bytes
x = np.fromstring(blob.content, dtype='uint8')

# decode the array into an image
img = cv2.imdecode(x, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print img.shape

# show it
cv2.imshow("Image Window", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: cv2.imdecode is not able to deal with the EXIF orientation. Hence some of the images seem rotated by 90 degress. cv2.imread and browsers do correction for the rotation. Any suggestions for how to deal with it?