# How to manage python paths in Azure?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, opencv

So basically how can I manage things that I do with images using opencv and PIL in Azure while hosting?

For my local hosting I can do:

```
cv2.imread("Upload//img1.jpg")
```

I am pretty sure I get a 500 code if I host a code with the above line. So what will be equivalent to above line in azure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read an image from Azure blob storage directly using Opencv without downloading it to a local file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44588402/how-can-i-read-an-image-from-azure-blob-storage-directly-using-opencv-without-do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my localhost was in Windows but I had hosted my site in Azure linux server. `cv2.imread("Upload/img1.jpg")` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to read file using relative path , here is something which you can try :

```
img1 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'images', 'main_image.jpg')
main_image = cv2.imread(img1)
```

Instead of using  :

```
main_image = cv2.imread('Upload/image.jpg')
```

Hope it helps.